# UICollectionView: Scroll to top and perform action when scrolling finished

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview

I scroll my collection view to the top and would like to perform an action once the scrolling is finished. Is there any way to achieve this easily?

Scrolling to the top could be done by using

- `setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))`
- `scrollRectToVisible`
- `scrollToItem(at: IndexPath, at: .top)`

Unfortunately none of these functions takes a `completion` block, and if I use the `animated = false` parameter, I could embed it in an `UIView.animate()` call and use its completion block - but then the collection view will reuse/not even display the collection view cells during the scroll.

Is there any way to do something on scroll completion except setting up a timer that hits after a certain time or doing some strange magic with flags & the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate function?

Answer (score 2):

Since `UICollectionView` confirms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`. Use this delegate function :

```
public func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
     if collectionView.contentOffset.y == 0
     {
          // perform your action
     }
}
```

This will be called when scroll stops.

Comment: As I don't want to refresh every time the collection view scrolls this falls under the "do some magic with flags" point - I would have to set a flag like "doRefreshOnScrollDecelerate". I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: There isn't any other way I am aware about. I hope you find a better solution.

Comment: And I don't think there is any requirement of setting a flag to achieve this. Not even by this approach.

Comment: Yes - how else would you distinguish a scroll to the top by the user manually from scrolling to the top programmatically?

Comment: But I feared there isn't any other way - have been searching (and waiting for a completion block) for this for years already ;-)

Comment: Like I shared above. Just compare the contentOffest. There are two things : 1) Check if the scroll has stopped,  which you can check by this delegate function. 2) Collection view reached to top - you can check this by contentOffest.
So there is really no need of taking a variable like doRefreshOnScrollDecelerate

Comment: Your idea and thought on the solution is in the right direction. But unfortunately, there isn't a completion handler for this event yet.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work when you're using `scrollToItem`, despite the animation decelerating.